# What the differences between clk_id of clock_gettime system-call

Tags: c, linux, time, system-calls

I tried to get the time through:

`int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp)`

I am confused about what `clk_id` I should put. There is:

```
CLOCK_REALTIME
CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE
CLOCK_MONOTONIC
CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE
CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW
CLOCK_BOOTTIME
CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a summary of some, check out the man's page with `man clock_gettime`

```
 CLOCK_REALTIME   identifies the realtime clock for the system.  

 CLOCK_MONOTONIC  identifies a clock that increases at a steady rate
                  (monotonically). 

 CLOCK_BOOTTIME   identical to CLOCK_MONOTONIC, except it also includes 
                  any time that the system is suspended.

 CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID
                  identifies a per process clock based on tick values.

 CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
                  identifies a per thread clock based on tick values.
```

Comment: can you explain more about `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, what's mean steady rate?

Comment: CLOCK_MONOTONIC represents the absolute elapsed wall-clock time since "some unspecified point in the past". It isn't affected by changes in the system time-of-day clock.

If you want to compute the elapsed time between two events observed on the one machine without an intervening reboot, CLOCK_MONOTONIC is the best option.